# scanf problems involving string input and string comparison

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I have just recently started working on scanf and printf in general, and in my research and general screwing around I have run into the problem in my code multiple times so I decided to make a test program and have successfully replicated the error.

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    std::string name;
    std::string name2;

    printf("Print donald or larry: ");
    scanf("%s",name);

if(strcmp(name.c_str(), "donald") == 1){
    printf("You entered donald");
    goto stop;


}else{
    printf("You entered larry");
    goto stop;
}



stop:
return 0;
}
```

when I attempt to compile the code it throws me an error coming from line 10

error:

```
error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'std::string {aka
class std::basic_string<char>}' through '...'|
```

source:

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

I have tried both `name.c_str` and `&name` and they both don't work, `name.c_str` makes the if statement bug out and not work but `&name` just crashes altogether, although I have found that `&<variable>` only works with integers so far.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `if(strcmp(name.c_str(), "donald") == 1){` Nope.

Comment: C or C++.  Pick one, leave the other.  If you want C++, try [`cout` and `cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/).

Comment: Decide whether you are coding in C or C++. If C, scanf is cool but forget `string`. If C++, `string` is fine, but no more scanf: `std:cin >> name;`

Comment: This is C++, scanf is probably better to use when programming in C

Comment: This post appears to be contrived.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char \*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857544/warning-format-s-expects-type-char-but-argument-2-has-type-int)

Comment: This ` scanf("%s",name);` will not work. Why are you using `goto`.

Comment: Assuming you are using C++ (and this is a big assumption) `strcmp(name.c_str(), "donald") == 1` can be written `name == "donald"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to write C++ code then use the following

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
#include <string>
using std::string;

int main(){

    // declare the string object
    std::string name;

    // output prompt and get input
    cout << "Print donald or larry: ";
    cin >> name;

    if (name == "donald") {
        cout << "You entered donald" << endl;
    }
    else if (name == "larry") {
        cout << "You entered larry" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You were doing some things "wrong" in your code above.

1. scanf and printf are C functions and should be used with cstrings not `string` objects.  If you are using `std::string`, then you are programming in C++ and you should use the functionality provided by the C++ standard library header `<iostream>`
2. Using `goto` in your code is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

> What am i doing wrong?

The primary issue is you are mixing *apples* and *oranges* (or C and C++) in this case. While it is possible to mix C/C++ I/O, it is not recommended for a number of reasons. Your declaration `std::string name;` attempts to declare a C++ string object which is not the same as a fundamental `char *` type. Thus when you attempt to fill the C++ string object with a basic C `scanf` you get the error. Why? Because `scanf` expects a simply `char *` pointer for name and you are providing a C++ *string object*. So it is best to either stick with *apples* or *oranges* and not attempt to mix C++ objects with standard C functions.

If you are attempting to write C code to investigate the `scanf` family of functions, then you will want something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXCHR = 64 };

int main (void) {

    char name[MAXCHR] = {0};  /* simple character array initialized to 0 */

    printf ("Print donald or larry: ");
    if (scanf ("%63[^\n]%*c",name) != 1) {  /* check the return of scanf */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (strcmp (name, "donald") == 0)       /* string comparisons */
        printf ("You entered donald\n");
    else if (strcmp (name, "larry") == 0)
        printf ("You entered larry\n");
    else
        printf ("You entered '%s' (neither 'donald' or 'larry')\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_name
Print donald or larry: donald
You entered donald

$ ./bin/scanf_name
Print donald or larry: larry
You entered larry

$ ./bin/scanf_name
Print donald or larry: moe
You entered 'moe' (neither 'donald' or 'larry')
```

If you are going to work with `scanf` (or any of that family of functions), then it is well worth the time spent to carefully read and digest the manual pages for the functions. There are a number of subtle caveats to the *format-string* and *format specifiers* that can bite you if you do not understand them fully. The `scanf` family of functions have their place, but consider using *line-oriented* input functions when taking input from users (e.g. `fgets` or `getline` in C) which are much less prone to subtle I/O issues.

Answer (score -5):

`scanf` doesn't support any C++ classes. If you want to read into a C++ `string`, you can do something similar to:

```
std::string str(256, ' ');
if (1 == scanf("%*s", &str[0], str.size())) {
    // ...
}
```

This doesn't explain, however, why you don't want to use `cin`.

Comment: `scanf("%*s` --> "An optional assignment-suppressing character *.", --> no `&str[0], str.size()`.

Comment: This is mixing C and C++ strings.  I do not agree with this at this instance

Comment: Works with some string implementations, but not others. Use with caution. Best to not use at all.